# ImportError: cannot import name 'AFAVSignature'

Tags: python-3.x

I get this error after already having installed autofocus when I try to run a .py file from the command line that contains the line:
from autofocus import Autofocus2D

Output:
ImportError: cannot import name 'AFAVSignature'

Is anyne familiar with this package and how to import it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the library is supported for python 3. I was getting the same error, but removed that line from **init**.py and found that there was another error with of something like 'print e' not working, so I put the line back in and imported with python2 and it worked.